# HttpClient on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm really curious as how [JIQL](http://code.google.com/p/jiql/) admin demo was able to run on Appengine cloud (appspot.com)

Whereas where I tried to port the available sources like the Guestbook and the Jqladmin app I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:176)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 44 more
```

However, there is a running JiqlAdmin that runs on top of GAE and I have tried and was able to execute a SQL query:

http://jiqladmin.appspot.com/Jiqladmin.html

Just wondering what went wrong in my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error seems obvious, you should add Apache commons Http client as dependency. Try putting that in your war/WEB_INF/lib or add it as dependency in Eclipse.

Comment: I do have the Http Client jars in the WEB-INF\lib that's why I quite unsure as to how the app was able to run in appengine, I don't think that HttpClient work with GAE

Comment: I ended up having this error in my app: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
So it's quite a mystery on how jiqlAdmin was able to run in GAE

Comment: I ended up having this error in my app: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
So it's quite a mystery on how jiqlAdmin was able to run in GAE

Comment: google appengine dont allow us to make plain http requests(since each request is going to be billed and is part of a quota). Please see URlFetchAPI offered by appengine.

Comment: please see http://esxx.blogspot.in/2009/06/using-apaches-httpclient-on-google-app.html